# Photo wrong thumbnail

Tags: macos, mac

In the Finder of my mac, it often happens that some photos in a folder are displaying wrong previews. The set of photos which have this problem is random and unpredictable: sometimes among 10 photos in a row there is one with a wrong thumbnail. The wrong thumbnail is always another photo in the same folder. Rebooting the machine does not help, which means the wrong information is stored somewhere. When I duplicate the photos (as an experiment), the new copy is OK.

I wonder if there is a way to force refreshing the thumbnails.

MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2014), OS X Yosemite (10.10.2)

I have also asked this question on https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6988345 but received no answer yet.

Comment: First thing I'd do is run Disk Utility, Verify Disk.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things you can try:

- Open the folder in Finder - click on the Actions button- select Show View Options - put a check next to Show icon preview. If it's checked, uncheck it, close the window, open it back up and check it again
- Head for your home folder - Library / Preferences - move the com.apple.finder.plist file to the desktop - log out and back in. If this fixes it, you can delete the file. This is going to reset all your Finder preferences to default.
- the thumbnails are stored in a folder called `com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache` in a subfolder of `/var/folders`. The quickest way to locate it should be to run `sudo find . -name com.apple.Q*`. You could move that folder to a different location and restart the Finder process (`killall Finder`) to force a recreation of the thumbnails.

Comment: I can't find the thumbnail folder, even if I use the command "sudo find . -name com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache* ". I go to /var/folders but there are only two subfolders named 5z and zz. I am using Yosemite 10.10.3.

Comment: Inside Library / Preferences there is no com.apple.finder.plist. Only com.apple.FindMyMac.plist starts with "f".

Comment: inside those two subfolders called `5z` and `zz` you will find two more folder levels; the next level will be rather cryptic names names like `6j_hj4590t37m93wj_ba0p040320gp`, the next level will be a single letter or number and inside these "single char folders" you will find the `com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache` on. Do the following to locate them: `sudo bash`   `cd /var/folders`    `find . -name com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache`